# What BJJ techniques are practical in real street fight

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, streetfight

Are there any Brazilian-jiu-jitsu (BJJ) techniques that can be used in real life street fights? Is there any source that lists them all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. At least in Gracie style BJJ, the focus is all on self-defense from the beginning. Sport adaptations are taught, but because of the emphasis on self-defense from the beginning, students generally understand when an adaptation might be dangerous in self-defense. Some schools point it out continuously. The competition oriented BJJ schools that don't do this can lead students to doing things that get them hurt in self-defense. Still, I'd take competent sport BJJ and Judo over most/all traditional martial arts if my life depended on it.

Comment: Now, if you're asking about the self-defense (classical jujitsu) kata taught in Gracie JJ, it's still in the system and is taught. You can pull up youtube videos showing it. They have a pretty extensive list of techniques, including strikes and small circle joint manipulation done in the context of self-defense.

Comment: Almost anything *could* be useful in a street fight, but only if practiced realistically against a resisting and attacking opponent. But takedowns, sprawling, and doing joint locks and chokes could obviously come in handy when you're only fighting one guy.

Comment: Thing about take-downs is that you don't need to follow them to the ground. Those who are trained at grappling are often the best at remaining standing if they want to resist being taken to the ground. They're the best at putting someone on the ground.  And they're the best at getting up from the ground when they want to. It's really quite practical to be trained in grappling in general. I would add boxing and muay thai in order to complete the skill set. In other words, more or less MMA.